# where should we use PL/SQL Records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

what is the main use and purpose of **PL/SQL Records**, where should we use **PL/SQL Records**

```
    declare
  type locationRecordType is record (
   streetAddress       varchar2(40),
   postalCode          varchar2(12),
   city                 varchar2(30),
   stateProvince       varchar2(25),
   countryID           char(2) not null := 'US'
  );

 myLocation locationRecordType;
 begin
    myLocation.streetAddress := '4564 Culloden';
    myLocation.postalCode := '20190';
    myLocation.city := 'Regina';
    myLocation.stateProvince := 'SK';
    dbms_output.put_line( 'MY LOCATION IS:' );
    dbms_output.put_line( myLocation.streetAddress );
    dbms_output.put( myLocation.city||', '||myLocation.stateProvince )
    dbms_output.put_line( '  '||myLocation.postalCode );
    dbms_output.put_line( myLocation.countryID );
    end;
```

Comment: This question is a programming question and does *not* belong on dba.se.com . So whoever voted to close as off-topic was wrong to do so.

Comment: The [concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/srvrside.htm#autoId14) has a brief introduction and links to more thorough documentation. You might need to be more specific about what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL records are complex variable data-types.

As you know, in PL/SQL our queries must SELECT into a variable.  If the query is a SELECT * we can define a variable using the `%ROWTYPE` syntax, e.g.

```
emp_rec emp%rowtype;
```

If we are selecting a single column we just define the variable with the appropriate data type, e.g. for SELECT COUNT(*) it would be

```
emp_cnt pls_integer;
```

But suppose our query has a more complicated projection?  Say if comprises only a few columns from a table?  Or some columns from several tables joined in the query?  In that case we would want to define a PL/SQL record.

Records should always populated with SELECTs, not assignments as you show.  The other caveat is that we cannot use records in DML statements such as FORALL.  If you need to do either of those things you probably ought to be using a SQL type instead.